# Template parameters in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Suppose I have arbitrary template method, which could receive parameters **by value** and **by const reference** *(obviously, for trivial types and for objects accordingly).*

How is this situation handled when writing template function prototypes?

I could make something like:

```
template <typename T> void Foo(T value) {
   // Do something.
}

template <typename T> void Foo(const T& value) {
   // Do something, yeah.
}

// Specialization for first prototype. 
template <> void Foo<int>(int value) { }

// Specialization for second prototype. 
template <> void Foo<Object>(const Object& value) { }
```

But this approach is only okay for trivial functions, that act purely as a wrapper for some other calls.

If the function *(non-templated version)* has a lot of code inside it, this means *I would have to copy the code twice.*

***Can I make something smarter here?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just take by const reference ALWAYS, because there isn't much overhead in passing primitive types as const references.

Comment: One doubt. If I have something like void foo(const complex& obj1) and I call this like foo(2), what will happen? (Assumming that I have copy constructor for int type.)

Comment: @Manoj: Then a temporary `complex` object is created (initialised with `2`) and passed to the function. This temporary will live until the end of the expression containing the function-call.

Comment: @Manoj: const references, unlike non-const ones, can bind to rvalues, so don't worry about that

Answer (score 5):

Write your template code for `const` references only and rely on the compiler to optimize the references away.